# Referencing elements in xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

is it possible to "reference" elements in xsl-fo? What I am trying to do is the following:

```
<fo:marker marker-class-name="continued">
<!-- much much more xml text content -->
</fo:marker>

<--.....-->

<fo:table-body>
 <fo:table-row>
  <!--at his point I'd like to "reference" (or copy) the marker from above -->
 </fo:table-row>
 <!--many more rows which reference the same marker -->
</fo:table-body>
```

The reason for this is that if I have a lot of rows in my table and the marker content is large then the xml simply gets too big. I have tried the xsl:copy-of element, since this looks what I'm trying to do:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_copy-of.asp

But this won't work with my fo, appearently the copy-of elements are ignored since I'm not getting any table headers in the output. Any ideas? I'm using the ecrion fo renderer.

Thanks

Stefan

Comment: You are misunderstanding the scope of XSL-FO, which does not accept XSLT syntax. You can write an XSLT which produces XSL-FO, and then there use an XSLT instruction. Otherwise, you must search for a suitable element among the XSL-FO objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fo:retrieve-marker`.

For example:

```
<fo:marker marker-class-name="continued">
<!-- much much more xml text content -->
</fo:marker>

<--.....-->

<fo:table-body>
 <fo:table-row>
  <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="first-including-carryover"/>
 </fo:table-row>
 <!--many more rows which reference the same marker -->
</fo:table-body>
```